# Allowing more elements in comments via functions.php

Tags: comments, html, wp-kses

I would like to allow certain HTML elements in my comments and have edited `kses.php` directly in the past.

However, I have been hacked recently and replaced all the core Wordpress files and feel I would like to avoid editing those files.

Is it possible to allow more elements via the `functions.php` file?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example how to allow a commenter to insert HTML5 video into the comment. Both `<video>` and `<source>` elements has two allowed attributes. `preprocess_comment` filter is applied when saving the comment to the DB.

See `/wp-includes/kses.php` for `$allowedtags` array structure.

```
function myAllowHtmlComments($comment) {
    global $allowedtags; 
    $allowedtags['video'] = array(
        'width' => true,
        'height' => true
    );
    $allowedtags['source'] = array(
        'src' => true,
        'type' => true
    );
    return $comment;
}
add_filter('preprocess_comment','myAllowHtmlComments');
```

Comment: That looks great, thank you.  I have added it to my functions.php but my internet connection is not working properly so I can't test it yet.

Comment: Okay, I have tested it and it seems to work perfectly.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Phillip, if so, please accept the answer.