# wp_filter_kses allow HTML5 video?

Tags: wp-kses

Is there a way to allow my users to add HTML5 video tag (without shortcodes) into my textfield/textarea?
Allowed anchor styles and bold tags are working, but as soon I add 'video' and 'source' it doesn't work anymore:(

Any help is appreciated. Thx.

```
function validate_setting($plugin_options){ 
    //This Works
    $allowed_html = array(
     'a' => array(
    'href' => array (),
    'title' => array ()),
    //This works also
    'b' => array(
    'style'=> array(),
    ),
     //This is not working...
    'video' = array(
    'width' => true,
    'height' => true
     ),
     //This also is not working...
    'source' = array(
    'src' => true,
    'type' => true
     ),
     );


$plugin_options['text_area']= wp_kses($plugin_options['text_area'],$allowed_html);
return $plugin_options;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok [This Thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77214/allowing-more-elements-in-comments-via-functions-php/77216#77216) did helped me a LOT!

So now my function works (i can embeld HTML5 videos) and it looks like this:

```
function validate_setting($plugin_options){ 

global $allowedtags;
$allowedtags = array(
'a' => array(
'href' => array (),
'title' => array ()),
'b' => array(
'style'=> array(),
),
);

$allowedtags['video'] = array(
    'width' => true,
    'height' => true
);
$allowedtags['source'] = array(
    'src' => true,
    'type' => true
);

$plugin_options['text_area'] = wp_kses($plugin_options['text_area'],$allowedtags);
 return $plugin_options;
}
```